# LaTeX places table outside of page margin

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I'm using the KOMA class scrbook with the font Tex Gyre Pagella (11pt) and onehalf-spacing. I am placing a table float with the position options "htb", but both pdflatex and lualatex place the table outside the textbody. The table is positioned at the bottom at the page but goes way into the bottom margin.

I am using TeXLive 2014 on archlinux x64. `lualatex --version` prints `Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (rev 4971)`.

MWE (include Tex Gyre Pagella and one half spacing). I used `showframe` to visualize the margins:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,
                twoside=true,
                parskip=half,
                fontsize=11pt,
                BCOR=3mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% both font and onehalfspacing are imperative for this example
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing{}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.

Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.


\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Table caption}
\label{tab:label1}
\vspace{2mm}
{\small
\begin{quote} 
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
\end{quote}
}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \toprule 
        \multirow{2}{*}{
            Parameter~$b$
        } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Parameter $h$} \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
         & 4 & 2 & 1\\ \midrule     
        360 & 0.0123 & 0.0123 & 0.0123\\[-2mm]
         ~ & {\scriptsize $\times 20$} & {\scriptsize $\times 20$}& {\scriptsize $\times 20$}\\[1mm]
        360 & 0.0123 & 0.0123 & 0.0123\\[-2mm]
         ~ & {\scriptsize $\times 20$} & {\scriptsize $\times 20$}& {\scriptsize $\times 20$}\\[1mm]
        360 & 0.0123 & 0.0123 & 0.0123\\[-2mm]
         ~ & {\scriptsize $\times 20$} & {\scriptsize $\times 20$}& {\scriptsize $\times 20$}\\[1mm]
        360 & 0.0123 & 0.0123 & 0.0123\\[-2mm]
         ~ & {\scriptsize $\times 20$} & {\scriptsize $\times 20$}& {\scriptsize $\times 20$}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\subsection{next subsection}
\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table gets positioned inside the page margin]

Can anyone help me?

PS: Trying out different placement options like "bt" or "tb" helps in this MWE, but that doesn't change the fact that the behaviour using "htb" is not expected. I can't change every float.

PPS: Depending on text size, I also had latex place the float above the text:
[image: Table gets positioned above text]

Comment: you have this because of [htb] and \vspace{2mm} if you delete \vspace you will be okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` fixed the problem (Miktex with Lualatex on Windows) [2].

When using `\begin{center}...\end{center}` additional vertical space is  introduced inside the float environment. I suspect this might throw off LaTeXs computing of margins.

In general the usage of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` is discouraged in floating environments and you should use `\centering` instead[1].

#### Update:

As suggested by user egreg, the combination of the `setspace` package and the `center` environment in floats is especially dangerous. Despite positioning of the table using the `center` environment works when removing the `setspace` package, I would suggest sticking with `\centering` to avoid future headaches.

---

#### Example usage of `\centering`

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Table caption}
    \label{tab:label1}
    \centering
    Descriptive text
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        ...
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

---

[1] Section 3.1 of "An essential guide to LATEX 2ε usage - Obsolete commands and packages" (http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf)

[2]

[image: positioning of fixed table]

Comment: I suspect that `setspace` monkeys with `center`. Good answer!